# WPF Data trigger to apply label and child?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

i have the following xaml where if Status is OK then label background is green, and if ERROR label background in red, this works fine for the parent label, but when i add a child i also want  that to adopt the parent background color? is there a way to allow the datatrigger to act for both parent and child labels ?

heres the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="wpfdemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfdemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="50" Width="50" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parents}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ParentColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!-- Parent label -->
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   x:Name="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="White"/>

                <!-- Errors -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"
                          Grid.Column="1">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child}">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="White"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- Parent is ok -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                         Value="OK">
                    <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Background" Value="#BF008000" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <!-- Parent is error -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                         Value="ERROR">
                    <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Background" Value="#BFFFFF00" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just set the Background of the ItemsControl that shows the errors? Note also that you would usually use TextBlocks instead of Labels to display texts.

Answer (score 0):

TargetName is control's name,not type.

try :

```
<DataTemplate >
  <Label x:Name="ChildLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Status,RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Value="OK">
        <Setter TargetName="ChildLabel" Property="Background" Value="#BF008000" />
     </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: tried this with the above code, and ChildLabel is not recognised?

Comment: Have you code running now, but its not updating the child background still ?

Comment: try set child lable ```Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Label}},Path=Background}"```

Comment: Hi, nope still not updating the child ( maybe better to assign the background in the classes, and pass the parameter to the xaml? )

Comment: OK ive ditched the data triggers and set the background as a binding and set in the class seemed to be the less complicated way